# Generated Content with :Before or :After on Table Cell (TD)

Tags: html, css

Though I had found the workaround for my problem, I still would like to clarify some things.

Here's what I wanted to achieve: **a table with an image as separator between rows using generated content**

Here was my first effort: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vqqf/68/

As you can see, the generated content in the **table cells** (`td`) doesn't seem to render anything. I expected a red line underneath each rows.

Second effort: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vqqf/69/

I insert some content to the `content` property, ie. `content:".";`

This seems to do the trick in generating the content. However, *Firefox*, **unfortunately**, doesn't render it right, in that the *content* is in relation to the **whole page**. (Notice the red line at the bottom in FF?)

Third effort: ***.../70/*** *(Same link but change the last number to 70 - Sorry, I don't have the privilege to post more than 2 links yet)*

Giving the cells a `float` seem to fix Firefox's problem. However, the heights became inconsistent.

Last effort: ***.../72/***

Finally, I resort to applying the *content* into the **table rows** (`tr`) instead. And this did the trick for all major browsers (excluding IE7, of course).

Okay, so here are my questions:

1. Why can't this work with an empty `content` like most elements do?
2. Why does Firefox render it in relation to the whole page (*see second effort*)? Is it a bug on FF side?
3. Is it a bad practice applying content into the table rows (`tr`)?

(Note: this question is regardless of the possibility of using *background image directly on the cells themselves* or using *borders*)